# How use loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I just started to learn java script for a few days. week i started to use loop i have quite confuses please help me.

it doesn't show the x ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var n,x;
    n = parseInt(prompt("N", "5"));

    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      for(j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        x += j;
      }
    } 
    x += "<br/>";       
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<div class=box>"+x+"</div>")
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and what's your question?

Comment: if you want to learn them.. here you go: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: What *does* it show or do? I suspect it will show "NaN" since `x` has never been initialized and `undefined + any_non_string -> NaN`. In any case, now is the time to **stop using document.write** and modify the DOM instead.

Comment: @user2864740 is living in the past.

Comment: @GolezTrol No, not really. w3schools used to be *terrible*; now it is just *sub par*. A beginner should be directed to *good* or *excellent* resources. Many can be found on the JavaScript info page - http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Comment: @user2864740 - W3Schools might not be a good source of tutorials in the past, but its reputation has been going quite high lately. Quoting from [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/), "For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience."

Comment: I presume you know PHP. You're treating Javascript like the PHP interpreter. So, a few things, script tags do not preserve state between them, unlike PHP. Also, Javascript does not write string literals directly into the DOM like PHP. You have to find a reference point and inject them.

Comment: @user2864740 - I'm not saying w3schools is the best place to learn JS (there're more that are better like codeacademy) but it is indeed a good place to learn JS. Easy introductions and no scary proper nouns give learners the confidence they need. Now take a look at MDN's tutorial. That is quite scary to a starter. Once they mastered the basics, more advanced references like the MDN should be consulted but meanwhile w3schools is still a good source for starters.

Comment: @user2864740 Sorry, it wasn't really meant as a personal attack. It's just that the whole w3schools discussion (and the fact that even w3fools agrees nowadays that it's a decent place to start) was just held (and deleted) seconds before you started again. So not only did I think your comment was outdated by content, I also thought is was funny because of the timing, though you probably couldn't know that.  So, I'm sorry if you are offendend. I only intended a friendly disagreement like Derek's.

Comment: @GolezTrol Fair enough, and I did get overly heated. I've removed my previous comments (except for the one with the link to the JavaScript info page); but I still hold that there are better resources to learn JavaScript from, granted some are "overly" technical.

Comment: Just so you know, JavaScript is one word, not two. You don't want to confuse JS with Java, they are two VERY different languages. I'm sure I'm not the only one who cringes every time they see it spelled as two words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code, you working example should look something like this:-

```
window.onload = function () {
   var n;
   var x = 0;
   n = parseInt(prompt("N", "5"));
   for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
           x += j
           document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML += x + "<br>"; //Append new results to the document
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3r372gv/)

Some mistakes to point are:-

1) You should not do `x+"<br>"` , that way you are treating it as a string type, but in further iterations of loop it will execute `x+=j`, thus it will output `NaN`. You should append `<br>` separately while writing to document.

2) Writing `document.write()` inside HTML seems a bit odd, especially if you want to print all values of `x`, you should write that statement in the loop , by referencing HTML element using its ID , and appending your new `x` to it

3) You have not included your script inside a function , enclose it in a function and call that function properly for execution, for example in my case I am calling it on `window.onload`

Comment: Also, always [use a radix](http://www.michaelgaigg.com/blog/2008/10/07/the-importance-of-the-javascript-parseint-radix/) with `parseInt`!